# OSX codesign Manually

Tags: macos, app-store, code-signing

I am trying to codesign an OSX application, i success in that. I can able to sandbox my application using --entitlements. But my issue is I have distribution Application certificate and distribution installer certificate. I signed using both of this. But i can't able to install that in my local machine because its for appstore. I need to set my provisioning profile to None so that i can install it manually and check the app. Is there any way to change this. My command is

```
codesign --entitlements "${ENTITLEMENTS_PATH}" --sign "$APP_SIGN_ID" --deep --force --verbose=2 "${DIST_APP_WITH_PATH}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Developer ID Application cert to sign items for use outside the app store.

Comment: I need a sandboxed application to test

Comment: @Jio I see, was there an issue achieving the sandboxing requirements?